# About App Submission?

Tags: app-store

I have submitted app on app store before 1 week. but after 5 days of submission my developer account expired. but immediately I have renewed that. 
so my question is after renew account my app take another 9 days for review or it doesn't matter of renewal of developer account.

Comment: Check in itunesconnect, how many days passed in "waiting for review" status. If apple reset your count days, you will see days from your renew account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever Apple doesn't send you mail for you need to activate your account for submit application. i.e. your application is waiting for review state. before that you have activated your account then apple doesn't reset days.

Answer (score 1):

Check in itunesconnect, how many days passed in "waiting for review" status. If apple reset your count days, you will see days from your renew account.

You can check this data inside Itunesconnect.com -> My Apps -> Your App.
Then go down and select the Link Status History inside Additional Information.

You can see status history with their dates.